# kerberos ticket seems corrupted after I invoke curl command

Tags: kerberos

Here's what I did in my secure cluster:

1. Invokding webhdfs command: "curl -s -i --negotiate -u:anyUser http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:50070/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS" (this works)
2. Invoking hdfs command: "hadoop fs -ls /"

But get the following error. (I need to kdestroy and kinti again to renew the ticket to make it work, looks like the first curl command make my ticket corrupted). This is weird, how can I make the webhdfs command not affect the hdfs command ?

16/02/23 03:38:41 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)] ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15"; destination host is: "sandbox.hortonworks.com":8020;

The only difference after step 1 in klist is that I have 2 extra HTTP principal, but I still have my principal jeff@EXAMPLE.COM

Default principal: jeff@EXAMPLE.COM Valid starting Expires Service principal 02/23/16 03:20:05 02/24/16 03:20:05 krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM renew until 02/23/16 03:20:05 02/23/16 03:20:10 02/24/16 03:20:05 HTTP/sandbox.hortonworks.com@ renew until 02/23/16 03:20:05 02/23/16 03:20:10 02/24/16 03:20:05 HTTP/sandbox.hortonworks.com@EXAMPLE.COM renew until 02/23/16 03:20:05

Comment: I guess you know about Steve Loughran's *"Kerberos and Hadoop"* GitBook and the trick about `export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true` plus `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` to get some detailed information about Kerberos failures  :-)  https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html

Comment: Clumsy workaround: manage *two* different ticket caches and switch with `KRB5CCNAME` env variable -- e.g. `export KRB5CCNAME="FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_$(id -u)_curl"; kinit -kt my.keytab me@MY.REALM; curl ......; unset KRB5CCNAME`